# How to get XMI File into pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, xmi

I hope it's no duplicate, but I've found nothing regarding my specific question.
I wonder if it's possible to convert an xmi file into a pandas dataframe by using pd.read_xml(). The read_xml functionality is available since pandas 1.3.4. I don't know too well about the differences between xmi and xml, but it seems that xmi is a special type of xml and these two types can not always be used identical.
So, is it possible to convert an xmi file into a pandas dataframe using pandas.read_xml() ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried it by now. It's possible getting data from xmi files into a pandas dataframe using pandas.read_xml().

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).